# Проверка на четность числа

Tags: python, if

Начинаю изучать Python и в процессе обучения столкнулся с таким вопросом. Почему для проверки на четность числа используется метод if x % 2 == 0: ??? Если я введу, например, вместо x - 4, то я получу 2, а не 0?

Comment: где ты получишь 2? Проверь сначала.

Comment: Кажется вы путаете операции деления (`/`) и взятия остатка от деления (`%`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знак "%" в python обозначает взятие остатка от деления. Т.е. если мы разделим 4 на 2, то получим 2, а остаток от деления равен 0. Или же, если мы разделим 3 на 2, то получим 1, а остаток от деления будет равен также 1, т.к. чтобы получить целочисленный ответ, нам не хватает 1. Так будет работать с любым нечётным числом.